# Find remainder of a large binary string when divided by a large number in cpp

Tags: c++, stl, c++14

I am trying to solve "Two set bits " problem on hackerrank.
Link to problem :[link](https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/smart-interviews/challenges/si-two-set-bits)

Essentially I have a large string in binary and want the remainder when divided by
this : 1000000007.

I am using bitset datatype for solving and the to_ullong() is causing an overflow when I convert the string to long long int.

Is there anyway to fiddle with bits of the string to get the remainder ?

Comment: You will have to implement your own remainder function (or a way to convert to some big number library datatype that can handle bigger numbers than `unsigned long long`).

Comment: By the way, Your link is broken

Comment: Please update the link so that the question is complete and one can validate the c++ code.

Comment: @bartop, sry  looks like it is private.

Comment: I Have a large string(around 1000 characters) , which is binary.Now i need to divide it by the given number as converting the binary string to decimal itself becomes too large to represent. The question said to print the remainder.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to answer your question when the statement is not public.
But using my psychic power I guess that your question is how to know the remainder of an arbitrary long bit sequence modulo `K = 1000000007`.

Assuming this is indeed the question, you could note your bit string as:

```
b_0 b_1 ... b_n
```

Its value is:

```
V = b_0*2^0 + b_1*2^1 + ... + b_n*2^n
```

Given the property of the modulo operation you have:

```
V % K = [ (b_0*2^0) % K + (b_1*2^1) % K + ... + (b_n*2^n) % K ] % K
```

For powers of two below `K` the computation is easy. For the others, you should use the modulo properties again:

```
V*W % K = [ (v % K) * (W % K) ] % K
```

For instance:

```
2^(1000) % K = [ (2^10) % K * ... * (2^10) % K ] % K
               \_______________  __________________/
                               \/
                           100 factors
```

Each modulo is easily computed and less than `K` making it fit for a `long long`.

Overall complexity will be `O(n*log(n))`, because you do `O(log(n))` operation to compute `2^n % K`, and you do this `n` times.